# Not able to #include "joystick.c";

Tags: c

```
#include "JoystickDriver.c";
#include "joystick.c";
task main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        getJoystickSettings(joystick);
    if(joy1Btn(8) ==  1)

    {
        motor[motorC] = 100;
    }
    else if(joy1Btn(7) == 1)
    {
        motor[motorC] = -100;
    }
}
}
```

This is to make a motor spin to intake balls into our robot.
The errors I got were:

```
File "C:\Users\Kunal Patel\Desktop\SourceFile002.c" compiled on Oct 12 2014 13:37:47
**Severe*:Couldn't open '#include' file 'joystick.c'
```

Comment: Where is the `joystick.c` file?

Comment: Do you have the `joystick.c` file in the directory you're compiling from? Is it readable? Is it spelled right (`JoystickDriver.c` starts with uppercase, so the naming scheme seems inconsistent otherwise)? Are you sure you want to `#include` .c files and not header files?

Comment: Also, do you *really* intend to be #include-ing .c files, instead of .h files?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using a semi-colon after the file name:

```
#include "JoystickDriver.c"
#include "joystick.c"
```

It is aconventional to include `.c` files in another; there can be good reasons for doing so, but they are few and far between, on the whole.

Were you actually looking for the `.h` files?

```
#include "JoystickDriver.h"
#include "joystick.h"
```

Whether it is C source or a header, you may need to specify a command line option so that the compiler knows where to look for the code.  The compiler will normally look in the directory holding the source code being compiled and in a bunch of system-defined places.  You may need to tell it to look somewhere else to.  On Unix, that would be with `-I /some/where/else`; the notation will be equivalent on Windows, but likely not identical.

Your declaration of `main()` suggests you are in an embedded environment.  If these comments don't help, you may need to cite your environment more carefully.

Comment: thank you, I realized that they updated robot c so JoystickDriver.c is what joystick.c was last year

Comment: Welcome to the real world!  Yes, APIs do change over time, but there really isn't a way for someone on SO to come up with that answer unless they've used the API for long enough to recognize the old and new names (and I, for one, have not done that).  You might like to think about how you could have modified your question so that it would be easier to spot the problem.  For example, "I'm using the joystick API for XXXXX available from YYYYY" including an appropriate URL for the 'from YYYYY' part.  And maybe there's a tag for that package, or the bigger hardware you're using.

Comment: I was just using the code given on the Robot-C wiki

Comment: It is fine to use code like that, though you should really give credit (or blame) where it is due.